# Xubuntu 20.04: No system info app :(

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, xfce, system-info

I am trying to make a Xubuntu distro. I have 1 problem. There is no system info app. If there is one that is pre-installed, where is it. Anyways, how do I get an app that tells me the System Information? I am running Xubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: What kind of information you need? A generic one is `lshw`.

Comment: A Xubuntu distro already exists, it is called Xubuntu.

Comment: FYI:  You're trying to make a *respin* of Xubuntu; `xfce4-about` will provide some details about the XFCE installed.  For hardware details there are numerous to choose from.

Comment: @mikewhatever I am trying to make a respin lol

Comment: In Ubuntu GNOME, you go into Settings, scroll to the bottom. There is an “About” tab. Can I get that in Xubuntu?